# Free riders and freeloaders

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, comparison

I am wondering about the spelling of these two words. 
Why is ["free rider"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/free-rider) spelled as two words, while ["freeloader"](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/freeloader) is only one? Is there a rule for this?

Furthermore, where is the exact difference between the two words or are they synonyms? When would we choose one over the other?

Finally, is this question better suited for this community or better in "English Language and Usage"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word "**freeloader**" dates from around 1940, combining the words **free** (in the sense of "without cost") and **load**, (meaning "put a burden or load on").

There is no specific explanation except that some words become *compound words* over time, often due to frequent usage.

I can't explain why **skateboard** has become one word when **ironing board** has not.

Or why **makeup** is a compound word without a hyphen but **make-believe** is hyphenated.

Perhaps "freeloader" is used more than "free rider"? Certainly, I have heard the former more than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Like Astralbee, I don't know why one is one word and the other is two. However, I can tell you a little about the distinction between them. The term "freeloader" carries a fairly negative connotation; it implies something disagreeable about the person. The term "free rider" is not quite as negative; it is sometimes used in economics, for example, to describe someone who benefits from the work that others do, while not necessarily implying that he or she is doing anything wrong. (I'm a native American English speaker; the distinction might be different in other countries.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/128873)

Comment: @Chenmunka It provides answers to two of OP's questions: "where is the exact difference between the two words or are they synonyms? When would we choose one over the other?"